# Wrong View shown (Catel)

Tags: catel

I'm trying to open a View with a ViewModel from my MainWindowViewModel.
It works, but all I get is a blank window. It binds the correct title but every other control is missing.

Did anyone have the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Show us the code. Are you using the UIVisualizerService? Or NavigationService?

Comment: What code do you need?
MainWindowViewModel, SettingsWindowViewModel and SettingsWindow?
I'm using UIVisualizerService.

Comment: Here's my SettingsWindowVM:
https://gist.github.com/Mythos94/0d9aa8fac57662dbd598

my SettingsWindow:
https://gist.github.com/Mythos94/11f5bf6dbb537c8632eb

my MainWindowVM Command:
https://gist.github.com/Mythos94/57ec114cfa0b2e0707a5

Comment: You did use AddDebugListener to see what is happening under the hood? All errors and warnings are logged.

Comment: Yes here's the log:
https://gist.github.com/Mythos94/652f620afdf3dff4b113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the call to **InitializeComponent** in your code-behind. Just a tip: create a base class with the Catel behaviors, then use that as a base view. It will keep your actual window code-behind much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, you forgot it here too:
https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+a+custom+window?src=search
I just copy pasted, I know that's lazy ;-)

Comment: I didn't forget it, because it is meant as a base, not as a partial code-behind.